# understanding orthogonal decomposition theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

The orthogonal decomposition theorem states:
"Let $W$ be a subspace of  $R^n$. Then each $\vec y$ in $R^n$ can be written uniquely in the form: 
$$\vec y= \hat y + \vec z,$$ where $\hat y$ is in $W$ and $\vec z$ is in $W^{\perp}$.

Later in one of the exercises, it's given that $\hat y$ is in $Row A$ for a given matrix a and $\vec z$ is in $Nul A$.

**What I don't understand is:** Why is each $\hat y$ in $Row A$ and not in $Col A$?  I don't get the intuition for this. Please avoid too much mathmatical derivation or computation, and explain things geometrically.

Comment: Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @gimusi, none of the answer address the 'geometric intuition' part

Comment: Ok I understand your point, I will revise that in order to find a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is a real $n \times n$ - matrix , then $(Nul A)^{\perp}=Col A^T= Row A$.

Comment: could you please describe this more geometrically?

Answer (score 1):

Recall that for any $v\in Nul(A)$ by matrix product rule

$$Av=0 \implies \begin{bmatrix}r_1\\r_2\\\vdots\\r_n\end{bmatrix}v=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\\vdots\\0\end{bmatrix}\implies\begin{bmatrix}\langle r_1,v\rangle\\\langle r_2,v\rangle\\\vdots\\\langle r_n,v\rangle\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\\vdots\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

therefore for each row $\langle r_i,v\rangle=0 \implies v\perp Row(A)$.

Answer (score 1):

For any $x\in \operatorname{Nul}(A)$ and any $y\in \Bbb R^n$, we have that
$$
0 = y^TAx = x^TA^Ty
$$
meaning that $x$ is orthogonal to $A^Ty$. This gives us $(\operatorname{Nul}(A))^\perp = \operatorname{Col}(A^T)$.